# Vue3 setup function results in error - cannot read property of email of null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around the setup function in Vue but am having trouble understanding why my user object fails to populate on page refreshes. If I make changes to the code, the user populates. So I know it's not an issue with the data itself, rather something I'm failing to understand in the Vue lifecycle.

The error: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null"`

Should I not be accessing the store in setup? Which hook would be best?

My simplified code.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  setup (props, context) {
    const { $store } = context.root;
    const user = computed(() => $store.state.auth.user);
    console.log(user.value.email);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you work this one out? I am having the same issue...

Comment: @fyllepo I did not. I moved the logic into a computed property and it worked.